# With root access, how do I access the OS-level notification system?

Tags: android

I am using a phone without LED notifications. I would like to dev an app to simulate that, however first, with root, I would like to get access to the notifications system on the OS level (so it can be app-agnostic), to get the notifications.

How can I do so, or where can I read up more about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your own firmware. This is not possible from an SDK application, rooted or not.

Comment: why do you say this? can you add more details to back up your answer?

Comment: @nubela: "why do you say this?" -- because it's true. "can you add more details to back up your answer?" -- the implementation of `NotificationManager` is in the firmware, running in a separate process from your SDK application. The only way to change `NotificationManager` is to write your own firmware. Rooting has nothing to do with it, other than perhaps making it easier for you to install replacement firmware on your personal device.

Answer (score 1):

Despite this being old and already having an answer accepted, I want to offer an alternative solution since I think the end goal can be achieved.  With all due respect to Mark, I think the direction the question is a little misleading, but the end goal is attainable.

If you are looking for something that would allow you to make an app that listens for notifications and then performs some action based on them regardless of the source app (or could be tailored to specific apps), then I think you can do this without writing firmware or rooting using an Accessibility Service.  Accessibility Services would allow access to notifications as they come in, allowing your app to do something with them.  You would be able to filter by the source package, get the notification contents, and a lot of other things.

There is a lot I could say on it, but it is still rather new to me, so I'll provide a couple of links to get started.

Accessibility Services page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

I would also recommend trying it out for yourself.  I came across a small project file that I was able to copy and run on my own as a proof-of-concept.  If you run this, you'll be able to see in the log that you really can read notifications: https://gist.github.com/qihnus/1909616

Don't forget to enable the accessibility feature for the app after you install it in your phone's accessibility settings.